# Compute the Integral accurate to 0.03.

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, approximation

**Integral**:$$I=\int_{0.3}^{2.0}\frac{e^{-x}\text{dx}}{(2+x-x^2)^{1/4}}$$

The function is not defined for $x=2$ ,which lies in the interval $[0.3,2.0]$. All the functions I've previously approximated were continuous over the entire interval $[a,b]$ where $a$ and $b$ were the bounds of the integral. How should one go about approximating integrals with discontinuities?

Comment: @user90369 The actual point $x=2$ does not matter of course (indeed you could just redefine the function there without making any real difference), but there is no way to carry out any of the usual bounds for methods like the rectangle rule or trapezoidal rule in the presence of a singularity. You have to excise the singularity and treat it separately.

Comment: @Ian: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to note that the singularity at $2$ is an integrable singularity, so that we can find a bound for $\int_{2-\delta}^2 f(x) dx$ which goes to zero as $\delta$ goes to zero. In this case $(2+x-x^2)=-(x^2-x-2)=-(x-2)(x+1)$, so its magnitude is greater than, say, $2|x-2|$ on $[2-\delta,2)$ once $\delta<1$. Similarly the magnitude of $e^{-x}$ is less than, say, $e^{-1}$ under similar circumstances. Hence

$$\int_{2-\delta}^2 \frac{e^{-x}}{(2+x-x^2)^{1/4}} dx \leq \int_{2-\delta}^2 \frac{e^{-1}}{2^{1/4} |x-2|^{1/4}} dx$$

provided $\delta<1$. But this integral can be explicitly calculated; it is some multiple of $\delta^{3/4}$. Note that for a function continuous on $[2-\delta,2]$, you would have a multiple of $\delta^1$, so the singularity is slowing down the decay as $\delta$ goes to zero. But it is not destroying it entirely, which is crucial.

Now you can compute $\int_{0.3}^2 f(x) dx$ as $\int_{0.3}^{2-\delta} f(x) dx + \int_{2-\delta}^2 f(x) dx$ where you choose $\delta$ so small that the second term is less than $0.015$ (so that in your solution you drop it entirely) and then compute the first term to within an accuracy of $0.015$ using whatever method you like.

There are more efficient ways to do this. For example, you could choose $\delta$ so small that the bound for the second term is merely less than $0.03$, and then approximate the second term by half of its bound. Since the integrand is also nonnegative, this will give an error of at most $0.015$. You'll get to use a slightly larger value of $\delta$ which will somewhat accelerate the convergence for the integration on $[0.3,2-\delta]$. You could also elect to partition the error in another way (devoting more of the error to one piece than the other).

Comment: thank you for your answer. Please define the term "Integrable Singularity."

Comment: @ShreyAryan "Integrable singularity" means that there is a singularity in the first place (in this case, the function blows up as $x \to 2^-$), but that the function can be integrated over a neighborhood of the singularity anyway, resulting in a finite number.